# How to set/remove cookie with jQuery using click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a button which adding/removing the extra `body` class on every click. I'm trying to set the proper class using jquery-cookie script.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var body_class = $.cookie('body_class');
   if(body_class) {
       $('body').attr('class', body_class);
   }
   else {
       $.removeCookie('body_class');
   }
   $(".contrast-btn").click(function() {
       $("body").toggleClass("extra-class");
       $.cookie('body_class', $('body').attr('class'));
   });
});
```

What is the problem?

When I click the button on start page, and go to the subpage the class is moving to all visited subpages - that is correct. When I click once again on button (but on subpage) the class on that subpage is removed - what is also correct. The problem is when I go to start page or other subpages (which I have visited) the `extra-class` is set but should be removed.

On console I have multiple cookies with different path name. Is it possible to do that after "second" click:

1. remove the `extra-class` class
2. remove all `body_class` cookies

Comment: what is `$.cookie` ? also, use `$('body').addClass()` instead of `attr()`

Comment: it is the function from jquery-cookie script

Comment: no kidding. maybe you could tell us which one.

Comment: also, i'm guessing you didnt mean to quote the variable name here: `$.removeCookie('body_class');`

Comment: There is a project called jquery.cookie https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie. There you can find both `$.cookie` and `$.removeCookie`. They are called from external file.

Answer (score 0):

Try smoething like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var body_class = $.cookie('body_class');
   if(body_class) {
       $('body').addClass(body_class);
   }else {
       // We already know this cookie doesn't exists at this point, so instead of trying to remove it,
       // this is where you want to SET it.
       $.cookie('body_class', "extra-class");
   }
   $(".contrast-btn").click(function() {
       $("body").toggleClass("extra-class");
       $.cookie('body_class', "extra-class");
   });
});
```